# Check if user has logged in from a different location with a dynamic IP?

Tags: php, dynamic, ip

I'm trying to make a system to check upon login if the user's IP is different than the their last IP. If the IP is different it will block the account. Most users have dynamic IPs. So on each IP change, the block account function will be triggered because the IPs do not match.

Is there a way to check whether the IP of the user is in some sort of class of the last IP?

Comment: I suggest you to use user's `MAC` address instead of `IP` as unique device identifier.

Comment: Blocking an IP because it's dynamic is definitely a bad approach. IP's change all the time, so unless you expect everyone to have a static IP address then I would look for an alternative.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: You could use a geolocation service. Many of them will return the ISP, and you can check if they're in the same ISP.

Comment: Dynamic IPs are not necessarily in similar address ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You should store user's MAC address and User agent header from last login, Because IP gets changed, You can get user agent like below

```html
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Which will give you something like this :

```js
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405
```

Here you can get Device, OS, Browser, etc. which is more relevant.